# How to change default background color of material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I make a dashboard for my company.
now I want to change some default style's material component.
for example I want to change background of `Paper` component.
I don't want to add my style for each component or make a new custom component.
In other words, I want to change default style of material components.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#fffff",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#010101",
    },
  },
});
const App = () => {
    return (<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                 .....
            </ThemeProvider>); 
}
```

You can look in their documentation.

- https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/
- https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/

Answer (score 0):

You can change styles like this:

1. You can change styles directly in the component if you dont want to create separate css file:

```js
<Paper  style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}>
```

this is good for small adjustment, if you add a lot of styles through this it will get messy and it will be hard to read.

2.Or you can add className to your component and create css file and change the styles from there:

```js
 <Paper className='papper'>
```

this is better if you want to add a lot of styles, your styles will be in separate file and it will be easier to read.